# JQuery Datepicker - Increment Date via href

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, increment

I have a JQuery datepicker range. I want to add two arrow buttons above it. When the left arrow is pressed both dates go down by one day. Opposite for the right.

The I currently have sets the date to the current date regardless of which arrow I press.

I'm only posting some snippets of code, because much of it is very similar (left arrow vs. right arrow and startdate vs. enddate)

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker({
onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
$( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
}
});
<script>

<script language="Javascript" type="text/javascript">
function reduceDate()
{

    var strCurrStart = $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    var strCurrEnd = $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
    var dateCurrStart = new Date(Date.parse(strCurrStart));
    var dateCurrEnd = new Date(Date.parse(strCurrEnd));
    dateCurrStart.setDate(dateCurrStart.getDate() - 1);
    dateCurrEnd.setDate(dateCurrEnd.getDate() - 1);
    var dateNewStart = dateCurrStart.toDateString();
    var dateNewEnd = dateCurrEnd.toDateString();
    dateNewStart = new Date( Date.parse(dateNewStart));
    dateNewEnd = new Date( Date.parse(dateNewEnd));
    $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "dateNewStart" );
    $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "dateNewEnd" );
    return 1; 
}
</script>
<div align="center">
<a href="#" onClick="return reduceDate();"><img src="Black-Left-Arrow.png" alt="-1d" border="0" height="15"></a>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<a href="#" onClick="return increaseDate();"><img src="Black-Right-Arrow.png" alt="-1d" border="0" height="15"></a>&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<br>
<form>
<label for="startdate">From</label>
<input type="text" id="startdate" name="startdate" value= <%=$strStartDate%> />
<label for="enddate">to</label>
<input type="text" id="enddate" name="enddate"  value= <%=$strEndDate%>>
<input type="submit" value="Update" ><input type="hidden" name= "query" value= <%=$query%> />
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: This code is all from an asp page and I am working with perl as my server side if that matters

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "setDate", "dateNewStart" );` to set the date. But, the setDate method only accept a date object or a string in a date format. but not a string like "dateNewStart".
Anyway, the setDate method accept "-1" or "+1".

So you can bind your buttons with this

```
$("#leftArrowDateStart").click(function(){
    $("#dateStart").datepicker("setDate", "-1");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the " around `dateNewStart` and `dateNewEnd` when you try to call `setDate` - otherwise, your are trying to set the dates as Strings instead of the Dates you created

```
    $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "setDate", dateNewStart );
    $( "#enddate" ).datepicker( "setDate", dateNewEnd );
```

But if you only want to subsctract one day, TCHdvlp solution, using `.datepicker("setDate", "-1");` is probably easier.